# How to make last elements of a nested menu clickable?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, recursion

I'm new to Javascript and React so please excuse if this is a dumb question. I've created this menu of nested json objects because I want users to be able to click items, which get put into their "bag". The only items in the menu that I want to be clickable are the very last ones of their nested objects, but I'm not 100% sure how to set up an onClick function to only be there for the "last" items. So basically, make it clickable if it doesn't have anymore children. I'll include screenshots of what I'm trying to accomplish as well. Does anyone have ideas on how to go about doing this?

Here's my code that renders the menu

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    categories: [],
    objectKeys: null,
    tempKeys: []
  };

  makeMenuLayer = layer => {
    const { objectKeys } = this.state;
    const layerKeys = Object.entries(layer).map(([key, value]) => {
      return (
        <ul key={key}>
          <div onClick={() => this.handleShowMore(key)}>{key}</div>
          {objectKeys[key] && this.makeMenuLayer(value)}
        </ul>
      );
    });
    return <div>{layerKeys}</div>;
  };

  handleShowMore = key => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      objectKeys: {
        ...prevState.objectKeys,
        [key]: !this.state.objectKeys[key]
      }
    }));
  };

  initializeTempKeys = layer => {
    Object.entries(layer).map(([key, value]) => {
      const newTempKeys = this.state.tempKeys;
      newTempKeys.push(key);
      this.setState({ tempKeys: newTempKeys });
      this.initializeTempKeys(value);
    });
  };

  initializeObjectKeys = () => {
    const { tempKeys } = this.state;
    let tempObject = {};
    tempKeys.forEach(tempKey => {
      tempObject[tempKey] = true;
    });

    this.setState({ objectKeys: tempObject });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://www.ifixit.com/api/2.0/categories").then(response => {
      this.setState({ categories: response.data });
    });
    const { categories } = this.state;
    this.initializeTempKeys(categories);
    this.initializeObjectKeys();
    this.setState({ categories });
  }

  render() {
    const { categories } = this.state;
    return <div>{this.makeMenuLayer(categories)}</div>;
  }
}
```

Here's my menu with some of the sections opened up. So to clarify, I'd want "Necktie" and "Umbrella" to be clickable, as well as "Patagonia Clothing" and "VAUDE Bekleidungsstück", but not "Tops", since that still has children.

[image]

here is the json data I am working with (when it's console.log'd)
[image]

Comment: Showing what your data structure looks like might help to understand your code better.

Comment: @SolomonOmojola I added a screenshot :)

Comment: just type check for object type like this `typeof value=='object' && this.initializeTempKeys(value);`

Comment: Please don't Post questions multiple times.

Comment: @VikashSingh sorry I thought I deleted this post since it wasn't worded how I meant

Answer (score 0):

If you map your entries with an index you can use it to detect the last entry:
`Object.entries(layer).map(([key, value], index) =>...`

And then for your component being rendered:
`onClick={index === Object.entries(layer).length - 1 && () => this.handleShowMore(key)}`

JavaScript will read the first statement before `&&` and if it returns true it will evaluate the next one. If it returns false, it doesn't go on to the next. So, your function will only be assigned to the last entry in your object.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but it throws an error when I try to put ```Object.entries(layer).length - 1 &&``` before an arrow in the ```onClick``` function...

Comment: I'm sorry. I may have messed something up. I'm on my phone. What is the error message?

Comment: It's a compilation error, when I hover over the ```()``` it says "expression expected" and when I hover over the ```=>``` it says " '}' expected". I think it is just now allowing there to be something before the ```()``` in an onClick function?

Comment: Did you remember to put `index === ` ?

Comment: Yes and I've also tried putting it in parentheses including the ```&& ()``` as well as not including it, but neither has worked